# HP Laserjet p1005 Printer quit working when I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 from 12.04

Tags: printing, 14.04, hplip, laserjet

My HP Laserjet p1005 Printer was working in Ubuntu 12.04, but when I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 it stopped working. The hplip is working, and also my printer is appearing in  the printers list. Also when I send a job, the computer sometimes shows that the job is successfully printed, (and sometimes the computer adds the job to the list of the jobs that are waiting to be printed), but nothing happens, it just doesn’t print anymore. Why?

Comment: See if `hplip` and `hplip toolbox` are installed. It works well to set up HP printers and scanners. Alternatively, you might check to see if `cups` is installed. The quickest way to check is `http://localhost:631/admin` in a web browser. You should be able to set up your printer that way too.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue, and after verifying the advice from Marc, I installed the latest
HPLIP (3.14.4 - the software Center installs 3.14.3 release) from http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install/install/index.html and I now I have the HP LaserJet P1005 printing fine!.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran hp-check and hp-doctor in command line and after asking some questions and downloading the plugin for my printer it fixed the issue with my hp laserjet 1018.